# Using same action in two vuex modules to separate logging logic

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

So I am developering nuxt app, using vuex as a store.
I came up with idea of having some logging (simple rest api requests to laravel backend), to log user's actions.

I found out that if I have two actions that are named the same in two different modules, both will be executed.

Is that acceptable practice? Or is it undocumented behaviour which will be fixed and removed?

Quick scheme on what is happening:

`store/index.js`

```js
import logging from './logging';
import search from './search';

const store = () =>
    new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
            logging,
            search,
        }
    });

export default store;
```

`store/search.js`

```js
const actions = {
    search(state, query) {
        // some search request and processing results
    }
};

const search = {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
};

export default search;
```

`store/logging.js`

```js
const actions = {
    search(state, query) {
        log(...)
    }
};

const logging = {
    state: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions,
};

export default logging;
```

Comment: You can use [namespaces](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) to isolate the modules with same members.

Comment: Hey @MatJ! Thanks for the commitment :)

The problem here that I don't want to have separate actions, for me having one `search` action that is handled in two different modules is fine goal -> I can separate actual request from logging and so on.
I was just wondering if it is normal practice or not :)

Comment: Oh!, That is fine, and is intended behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways:

1. use constants
2. use namespased modules

**Constants**:

create file: `constants/store.js`

```
export const LOGGING_SEARCH = 'logging search';
export const SEARCH = 'search';
```

then use it, e.g.:

```
import { LOGGING_SEARCH } from '../constants/store.js'
const actions = {
    [LOGGING_SEARCH](state, query) {
        log(...)
    }
};

const logging = {
    state: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions,
};

export default logging;
```

and call it

```
import { LOGGING_SEARCH } from '../constants/store.js'
store.dispatch(LOGGING_SEARCH, 'query');
```

**namespased modules** [doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing)

store/logging.js

```
const actions = {
    search(state, query) {
        log(...)
    }
};

const logging = {
    namespased: true,
    state: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions,
};

export default logging;
```

and call it

```
store.dispatch('logging/search', 'query');
```

Namespased modules are really helpfull especially with [helpers](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the commitment :)
The problem here that I don't want to have separate actions, for me having one `search` action that is handled in two different modules is fine goal -> I can separate actual request from logging and so on.
I was just wondering if it is normal practice or not :)

Comment: Hey! Yes, it is ok, in some cases it can be helpful. From documentatin: "By default, actions, mutations and getters inside modules are still registered under the global namespace - this allows multiple modules to react to the same mutation/action type."
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing

Comment: Cool, that what I missed while investigated documentation, thanks!